# How to do bind two dataframe columns in sparkR?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

How to bind two columns of dataframe in SparkR of spark 1.4

TIA, Arun

Comment: Could you clarify. What is the example input and expected output?

Comment: @zero323 the same as we do in R programming with cbind(). see for  [Example link](http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/cbind.php)

Comment: Is this supported in sparkR 1.5?

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to do this. Here is a question on spark (1.3) in scala. The only way to be able to do this, is having some kind of row.numbering, because then you are able to join on row.number. Why? Because you can only join tables or add columns based on other already existing columns

```
data1 <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, data.frame(a=c(1,2,3)))
data2 <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, data.frame(b=c(2,3,4)))
```

Then

```
withColumn(data1,"b",data1$a + 1)
```

is allowed, but

```
withColumn(data1,"b",data2$b)
```

is not. From the moment Spark cuts your DataFrame in blocks to store it, it has no idea how to bind them (it has no idea of a row sequencing), only when you have row.numbers.