# Get specific row by using SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I have a dataset "data" in SparkR of type DataFrame. 
I want to get entry number 50 for example.
In R I simply type `data[50,]` but when I do this in sparkR I get this message

> "Error: object of type 'S4' is not subsettable"

What can I do to solve this ?

Furthermore: How can I add a column (of the same column-size) to the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you can do is

```
all50 <- take(data,50)
row50 <- tail(all50,1)
```

SparkR has no row.names, hence you can not subset on an index. This approach works, but you do not want to use it on big datasets.

Also the second part of your question is not possible yet. You can only add columns based on numbers (e.g. a constant column) or by making transformations of columns that belong to your DataFrame.
This was actually already asked in [How to do bind two dataframe columns in sparkR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31589222/how-to-do-bind-two-dataframe-columns-in-sparkr).

Comment: Why should I not use it on big datasets? Because it takes time to run?

Comment: If you need element 7000000000, you should collect 7000000000 rows locally, which you do not want to do.

Comment: I have a DataFrame. To take the minimum- value in a column I simply do this:  first ( arrange(x) ). However if I want to take the maximum-value I should be able to do this in a similar way but I cant see a 'last' function for sparkR.

Comment: use first(arrange(x),desc(x$'column you sort'))

Comment: 'x' is my DataFrame and 'a' is a column in x. When I type first(arrange(x),desc(x$a)) I get "Error in sort(a): object a not found"

Comment: first(arrange(x,desc(x$a)): desc is an operation in arrange, not in first

Comment: What is the best alternative way to attach columns in a DataFrame to create a new DataFrame (which is a subset) ? I can attach one like this newdata <- filter(data, data$column == 1) but I can attach more like I use to do in R.

Comment: You should ask a new question to get more people to see your question. And actually, your code won't work in R neither, it should be %in% c(1,3,9,14), which probably does not work in SparkR neither.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on previous transformations order of values in `RDDs`, which are the data containers behind the Spark Data Frames, is not guaranteed. Unless you explicitly order your data, for example using `orderBy` asking for the nth row is not even meaningful.

If you combine explicit order and a little bit of a raw SQL you can select a single row as follows:

```
sqlContext <- sparkRHive.init(sc)
df <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, mtcars)
registerTempTable(df, "df")

# First lets order data frame and add row number
df_ordered <- sql(
     sqlContext,
    "SELECT *, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY wt) as rn FROM df")

# It could be done with using nested SQL but where is more convinient
head(where(df_ordered, df_ordered$rn == 5))
```

Please note that window functions require `HiveContext`. Default `sparkRSQL` context you get in a `SparkR` shell won't work.

It is worth to note that Spark Data Frames (same as any RDD) are not designed with random access in mind and operations like a single value/row access are not obvious for a reason. Sorting a large dataset is an expensive process and without specific partitioner extracting a single may require a whole RDD scan.

Comment: Which version of Spark do you run? Your sql query does raise an error at my machine (spark-1.4.0).

Comment: I use 1.4.1, but I am pretty sure it should work on 1.4.0. Can you provide some details?

Comment: As said, I use Spark-1.4.0 in RStudio, launched only with the extra package "com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3" and I get the error: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.29] failure: ``union'' expected but `(' found SELECT *, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY wt) as rn FROM df (it's pointing to the '(' before ORDER.

Comment: @WannesRosiers It looks like you are using a `SQLContext` not a `HiveContext`.